# How to change browser language of webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io, chrome-options

I would like to change browser language. but it is not working. default browser language is displayed..

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--lang=ja']
    }
}],
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still interested in making this work, the WebdriverIO implementation would be:

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: [ '--your-args-go-here',
                '--like-so',
                '--and-so-and-so' 
                // e.g: '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--start-fullscreen' 
        ],
        prefs: {
            'intl.accept_languages': 'ru,RU'
        }
    }
}]
```

- For the full list of **Chromium switches** (`args` array values), click **[here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)**.
- For the full list of **Chromium preferences** (`prefs` object properties), click **[here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc)**.

**Note:** another useful resource (*which is always up to date*) for Chromium switches is Peter Beverloo's [Chromium CLI Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) portal.

Using the above Chrome config in the `wdio.conf.js` & running an Instagram login test will successfully convert the locale of the page to Russian, as seen below:

[image]

Comment: I know it's an old post, but have you tested setting `prefs: { 'intl.accept_languages': 'ru,RU' }` AND running in headless? It seems to ignore the prefs in that case

Answer (score 1):

could you try this instead?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

check on webdriver io how to use add_experimental_option